# RSS parser in Google App Engine (Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine

What is the best approach to writing a super simple RSS parser in Google App Engine (Java)? I read few posts about Rome, but seems like Rome is not compatible with App Engine.

Am I better off writing my own library? Fewest lines of code is a requirement, as this is not the main function of the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I wouldn't think of RSS parser but focus on Atom parser instead. Atom feeds are clearly defined by [this RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5023.txt).

And you can access Atom version of any RSS Feed without any problem - that is the service (no login required) that [Google Reader API](http://code.google.com/p/pyrfeed/wiki/GoogleReaderAPI) gives you for free.

Parsing Atom Feeds would be trivial, just use XML parser of your choice.